# Constructing LS factor for RUSLE without outliers using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, hydrology

I'm using the following formula in RUSLE via raster calculator to obtain a LS factor

```
Power(Flowacc)*1/22.1,.4)*Power(sin(slope)*.01745/.09,1.4)*1.4
```

My expected outcome is a raster from 0 to approximately 53.  The range of my output raster is 0 to 6,0XX.  All of the raster is 0-53 except for concentrated flow areas which have the anomaly values.

Is there a way to exclude the anomaly concentrated flow values in formula or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error using a slope raster in percentage rise rather than degrees.

Comment: Slope must be expressed as radians

Comment: Yes, I think that is the function of the .01745 modifier in the formula.. to convert degrees to radians

Comment: No it is not. Or at least it has to be sin (slope*0.01745) or you'll end up with negatives to raise to power of 1.4

Comment: I am getting a significant amount of "no data" pixels in my LS factor.  What would be a correct raster calculation to use using the USPED method and accounting for proper conversion to radians?

Comment: What is  usped?  Provide hyperlink

Comment: I believe its a modified Burch/Moore approach.  Alternatively, what would you recommend for LS Factor calculation?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuup6Il5nMAhVigYMKHaPwDCsQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fengineering.purdue.edu%2FABE%2FPeople%2FPapers%2Fbernard.a.engel.1%2Fgis.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEm9CY6EZNSLWWMdDMlRhEg-PaiNQ&sig2=3wepL7Mww91WXQV990ZKOA

Comment: Simply copy equation from document, you messed up with (). And take care of units, e.g. slope raster - degrees. Under no circumstances it can result in NO DATA unless you have negative slopes or ones greater 180

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38557/discussion-between-jessi-fein-and-felixip).